# Reaper distributed patch dissemination design

Tags: virus, antivirus, worm

Academic literature describes a method for distributing benevolent patches "in which every newly patched node forwards the patches to some or all of its neighbors according to a well-designed protocol" [[1](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0137858)]. This is termed distributed patch dissemination [[1](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0137858)], countermeasure competing strategy [[2](https://doi.org/10.1109/TSMCB.2003.817098)], epidemic vaccine propagation [[3](https://doi.org/10.1038/nphys177)], or patch forwarding [[4](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apm.2016.10.028)] by various authors. This way, the patch *might* spread faster than it would if users/admins had to manually update their system to apply the patch.

I know of one potential use: the Creeper worm was removed with a Reaper counter-worm [[5](https://corewar.co.uk/creeper.htm)].

1. Does anyone have a reference/description of the implementation/design of Reaper? How did the authors ensure that Reaper spreads to disinfect the whole net, without spreading so much that it unintentionally degraded service? Presumably, a persistent ("sleeper-cell") Creeper variant would defeat a Reaper that deleted itself after a certain amount of time.
2. Has distributed patch dissemination ever been used since Reaper?

Comment: Like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/do/waas-delivery-optimization

Comment: Modifying a system without permission runs afoul of ethics and laws. One's intentions might be benevolent, but you might have no idea of the unintended consequences.

Comment: @schroeder specifically, Peer-to-peer is interesting (like torrent) but specifically the mechanism described in research is viral in a way that voluntary, peer-to-peer collaboration is not.

Comment: Paper 1 appears to suggest that P2P is a requirement. Paper 2 proposes a "countermeasure-propagation network". Paper 3 uses the term "a separate, overlapping, partially correlated network" but never suggests that the network isn't voluntary. I'm thinking that you might be adding the factor of the network not being voluntary.

Comment: As a side note, XDR is a technology that is also relevant here. Nodes provide telemetry which is sent to a central hub, which sends the countermeasure agent to the other participating nodes on the network. All this happens automatically without human interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the more common terms you are describing is a "[benevolent worm](https://www.google.com/search?q=benevolent%20worms)" or a "[helpful worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_worm#Worms_with_good_intent)", if you are describing a mechanism that works without consent or active participation by receiving nodes (like P2P). I'd use those search terms to further your research.

But as for your questions:

> How did the authors ensure that Reaper spreads to disinfect the whole
> net, without spreading so much that it unintentionally degraded
> service?

Keep in mind that there were only [28 vulnerable machines](https://smartermsp.com/the-creeper-and-the-reaper-make-cybersecurity-history/) on ARPANET at the time... and everyone knew each other ...

> ... without spreading so much that it unintentionally degraded
> service?

You're making an assumption that that was a design concern or that propagation could degrade service.

> Presumably, a persistent ("sleeper-cell") Creeper variant would defeat
> a Reaper that deleted itself after a certain amount of time.

Again, given the context, it is not reasonable to assume that this might be a design consideration seeing that the Reaper author was the author of Creeper (which was a "demonstration program" )...

Which brings us to:

> Does anyone have a reference/description of the implementation/design
> of Reaper?

And I don't think that you would gain anything from the design given the unique context in which it was created.

> Has distributed patch dissemination ever been used since Reaper?

Short answer: [yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welchia).

**To add:**
This is a really bad idea. As [Schneier points out](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/02/benevolent_worm_1.html), it keeps getting proposed, but it never gains traction because of the unintended consequences. A benevolent worm that breaks a server by mistake is no different from a malicious worm. There's a reason why patch programmes include testing and vetting before release into production environments.